# How are subpreambles handled by the standalone package?

Tags: acronyms, standalone, preamble, subfiles

I wrote two simple files integrated using the standalone package:

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\input{myfile}

\end{document}
```

myfile.tex:

```
\documentclass[class=article, crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}

\acrodef{FB}{Foo Bar}
First call: \ac{FB} \par Later calls: \ac{FB}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

While the subfile compiles as intended, the main file compiles with error:
[image: myfile][image: main file]

Seems like while the `\lipsum` and the `\ac` commands are both known to the main file, the `\acrodef` command is not so as suggested by the errors I get. Even if I move the `\acrodef` command to the preamble of the subfile, nothing changes.

The only way I could solve this so far was to add the *acronym* package also in the preamble of the main file while based on the documentation of the *standalone* package, this is what the *subpreambles* tag is expected to do and has already done with the *lipsum* package in this example.

So what am I missing or misunderstanding about the *standalone* package and how it handles the *subpreambles*?

### Update

With using the command `\newacro` instead of `\acrodef`, the issue with the command `\ac` gets solved. So the first call and the other calls to `\ac` successfully resolves to correct outputs. But still there is an additional line showing up in the output when compiling `main.tex` (the first line):
[image: using newacro]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `.aux` file where acronym puts the seemingly undefined stuff, is input before before the `.sta` file where `standalone` puts the subpreambles. The input of the `.sta` file happens when the `begindocument` hook is executed, which happens *after* the `.aux` file is being read.

However, there is a hook `begindocument/before` which happens *before* the `.aux` file is read.

In your example we can add the crucial code from `standalone` to this hook rather safely as your subfile only loads packages. Packages never get loaded twice so this is not a problem but custom definitions in a subpreamble may very well be a peoblem… use the following with caution.

Also: you should report this to the package author.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}

\makeatletter
\AddToHook{begindocument/before}{%
  \let\subpreamble\@gobble
  \let\endsubpreamble\relax
  \let\standalonepreambles\relax
  \let\endstandalonepreambles\relax
  \ifsa@sortsubpreambles
    \let\sa@orig@usepackage\usepackage
    \let\usepackage\sa@usepackagewithoutoptions
  \fi
  \InputIfFileExists{\jobname.sta}{}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\input{myfile}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! And to which author should it be reported? standalone or acronym? From your answer I guess the standalone package should be responsible for this, right?

Comment: @mhr yes, this needs to be changed in the `standalone` package